# Start an app and a function of that app when receiving an sms

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver

I like to Develop an app which will change phone sound profile to normal on receiving a particular sms. How to set up a Broad Cast receiver to start the app as well as to start the activity

this is my code. I have have given each image button a function( change sounde profile- vibrate,silent,general). I want to trigger the general button when receiving an sms in a particular format (eg: change to general)

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.media.AudioManager;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.ImageButton;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    ImageButton vibrate, silent, normal;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        vibrate = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.vibrate);
        silent = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.silent);
        normal = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.normal);

        final AudioManager audioManager =
                (AudioManager)
                        getSystemService(getApplicationContext().AUDIO_SERVICE);

        vibrate.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                audioManager.setRingerMode(AudioManager.RINGER_MODE_VIBRATE);
                Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Mode: Vibration ",
                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });

        silent.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                audioManager.setRingerMode(AudioManager.RINGER_MODE_SILENT);
                Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Mode: Silent ",
                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });

        normal.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                audioManager.setRingerMode(AudioManager.RINGER_MODE_NORMAL);
                Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Mode: Ringing ",
                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

please help

Comment: There are many, many examples available that demonstrate how to receive incoming SMS. Have you tried any?

Comment: @Mike sry..I have read some But could'nt understand it well.Can you help me in doing it?

Comment: I'm afraid this is not the right site for tutorials or step-by-step help. What you're asking, while not too difficult to do, does require several "moving parts". You're more likely to get help if you at least begin putting a solution together, and then come here when you hit a specific problem.